# Value of Optional.of("xxxx") in Java Programming

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Please consider the following java code:

```
Optional.of("some.constant.value")
```

How is using `Optional.of()` of any value when the parameter is a constant?

Comment: I don't understand. As opposed to what?

Comment: It's "useless" ..^^

Comment: It has little value in isolation, but may have been required due to some external circumstance.

Comment: Same as any other constant value, like `"foo"` or `1` or `null` or `false`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Optional is generally used as return value of a function that may or may not return a value. It's a technique to avoid dealing with null-values.

E.g. assuming you have a function that returns an `Optional<Integer>`, you can use it to provide a default value:

```
int x = person.getAge().orElse(42);
```

The factory function you are refering to is how an Optional is constructed in the called function:

```
public Optional<Integer> getAge(){
    if(this.age == null)
         return Optional.empty();
    return Optional.of(this.age);
}
```

Comment: Of course in your example you could just use `Optional.ofNullable`

Comment: True, but i wanted to point out the difference between `Optional.of` and `Optional.empty` and was too tired to think of a better example :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely contextual, and without that context it's impossible for anyone to really say.

But...  As a couple of times I've seen things like this be useful (maybe you can identify which one is relevant to your given circumstance:

---

An interface where some method is an `Optional`.

```
interface PotentiallyLimited {
    OptionalInt getLimit();
}

class LimitedToTen implements PotentiallyLimited {
    private static final OptionalInt LIMIT = OptionalInt.of(10);

    @Override
    public final OptionalInt getLimit() {
        return LIMIT;
    }
}
```

In this case, having the variable stored as a constant stops it having to generate a new instance every time.

---

A class where some dependency would return an `Optional`, but may not be present.

```
class Thing {
    private static final Optional<String> DEFAULT_PREFERENCE = Optional.of("blue");
    private final @Nullable PreferenceProvider provider;

    public void useDependency() {
        final Optional<String> preference;
        if (dependency != null) {
            preference = provider.getPreference();
        } else {
            preference = DEFAULT;
        }
        // Use the preference here...
    }
}
```

Again, having it as a constant means you don't need to create a new instance on every invocation.

---

One final case I've seen, say you have some interface which has a sort of `boolean isError();` and an additional `Optional<String> getErrorReason();`. It's perfectly reasonably to have an implementation which always represents an error, then explicitly setting the Optional from a known constant `String` again helps avoiding creating lots of instances.

---

I'm sure there's plenty of other times it might be useful to do this.